# sed in bash with variables and double quotes causes unterminated error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

I have the following code and I kept getting the `unterminated error`.
For example, `$1` can be `ABC-TXT-123` and I want to replace `TEXT abc.123` in the file with `ABC-TXT-123`.

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$1
if [[ $id =~ .*TXT.* ]]; then
    sed -i "s/TEXT abc.*/TEXT $id/" someDataFile
fi
```

Comment: I just tried it quickly and got no error?  You would need to provide us with the context causing the error, typically the argument that you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine with the following commands:

```
$ cat > test
asd asd asd asd
asd TEXT abc.123 asd
asd asd asd asd

$ var='ABC-TXT-123'
$ sed -i "s/TEXT abc.*/TEXT $var/" test

$ cat test
asd asd asd asd asd
asd TEXT ABC-TXT-123
asd asd asd asd asd
```

Maybe you could provide us also a snippet of the file...

Answer (score 0):

On OSX I had to include an extra `''` to make it work:

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$1
if [[ $id =~ .*TXT.* ]]; then
    sed -i '' 's/TEXT abc.*/TEXT '$id'/' someDataFile
fi
```

which means the content of someDataFile goes from 'TEXT abc.123' to 'TEXT ABC-TXT-123'. But your description asks for slightly different so you might want to:

```
    sed -i '' 's/TEXT abc.*/'$id'/' someDataFile
```

instead to replace the whole line and not put the word 'TEXT' back in...